# MySQL/Java - How can I do this SELECT statement?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a project that has multiple users. There are two user types the person who orders and the person who bids.

When the PERSONS WHO ORDER post orders. It will reflect to BIDDERS account. What I want is something like this, when a BIDDER hasn't bid for anything all the available orders for bid will appear to his account. I have two tables: ORDERS and BIDS

**ORDERS TABLE:**

```
OrderID|Item    | OrderStatus|
1      |Shoes   | On-Bidding |  
2      |Bag     | On-Bidding |  
3      |Shirt   | On-Bidding |
```

**BIDS TABLE:**

```
BidID | BidCost | BidStatus |BidderID  | OrderID |  
1     | $100    | Waiting   | 2        | 2       |  
2     | $200    | Waiting   | 1        | 2       |
```

The table that I want to display using JAVA is like this:

The AVAILABLE FOR BID table that will appear to the user:

For Bidder ID 2 (He bids for the bag so the BidCost column will be joined):

```
Order ID| Item  | BidCost |  
2       | Bag   | $100    |  
1       | Shoes | NULL    |  
3       | Shirt | NULL    |
```

For Bidder ID 1 (He also bids for the bad for $200)

```
Order ID| Item   | BidCost |  
2       | Bag    | $200    |  
1       | Shoes  | NULL    |  
3       | Shirt  | NULL    |
```

For Bidder ID 3(He didn't Bid Anything)

```
Order ID| Item  | BidCost |  
2       | Bag   | NULL    |  
1       | Shoes | NULL    |  
3       | Shirt | NULL    |
```

What I did was just SELECT all with the ON-BIDDING status and JOIN it with the BID Table for the BidCost. But everytime I do that. If someone has already bid for an item and another user has not, the bid cost will not appear to him/her as null. The bid of the other user will be joined. So that user will see the bid of another user.

How can I do this using MySQL and JAVA?

My QUERY:

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders T1 
INNER JOIN 
    SELECT bidcost 
    FROM bids T2 
ON T1.ID=T2.ID 
WHERE orderstatus=ON-BIDDING
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you want to archive. I cant get it by your explanation

Comment: Please be specific, say what you want to achive? If you want null values to appear in resultset just use OUTER JOIN.

Comment: @ZeusNet What I want is when the bidders doesn't bid for anything I want them to show all the ON-BIDDING orders but the bidcost will just be NULL. And if he bids for something, the bidcost will now show but only for the specific BIDDER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT * FROM orders t1 
         LEFT JOIN bids t2 on t1.OrderID = t2.OrderID and t2.BidderID = $user_id
    WHERE orderstatus=ON-BIDDING
```

Comment: You just solved my problem. You're a pure genius. I don't know why some people negatived my question, I know it's clear. Thank you. You don't know how much help you have given.